# cannot figure out how withIconOffset works

Tags: android, mapbox

I have been messing with withIconOffset to move center of anchor to exactly bottom of the icon.

It says "Positive values indicate right and down, while negative values indicate left and up", what does it mean? passing some values does move my marker around but cannot postion it correctly.

Also tried to divide my png icon height in half and move it up by that amount but it goes too far up.
`.withIconOffset(arrayOf(0f, -image.height/2f))`

Im using .withIconSize(2f) too, will it have any effect on offsets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my bad, forgot to convert image height to dp.

something like this works fine

```
val Int.dp: Int
    get() = (this / Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()
//...
.withIconOffset(arrayOf(0f, -image.height.dp/2f))`
```

edit:
I also found another way `.withIconAnchor(Property.ICON_ANCHOR_BOTTOM)`